# Issues retrieving project objectives from European Commission Funding & Tenders Portal using API

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am currently using the EC Search API to retrieve open project call data, and I'm having trouble retrieving the objectives for each project, which because objective section can be found after clicking the project name. While the API returns some useful information, it does not include the objectives field that I need.

Here is the link to website: [EC Funding & Tenders Upcoming HORIZON project calls](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-search;callCode=null;freeTextSearchKeyword=;matchWholeText=true;typeCodes=0,1,2,8;statusCodes=31094502;programmePeriod=2021%20-%202027;programCcm2Id=43108390;programDivisionCode=null;focusAreaCode=null;destinationGroup=null;missionGroup=null;geographicalZonesCode=null;programmeDivisionProspect=null;startDateLte=null;startDateGte=null;crossCuttingPriorityCode=null;cpvCode=null;performanceOfDelivery=null;sortQuery=sortStatus;orderBy=asc;onlyTenders=false;topicListKey=topicSearchTablePageState)

As you can see on the link, there are the project names. After clicking a project name, a new page opens and objective section can be seen there.

Also I have this code block and it can print project names and project keywords but I also need the objectives section for each project.

```
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://api.tech.ec.europa.eu/search-api/prod/rest/search"
params = {"apiKey": "SEDIA", "text": "***", "pageSize": "50", "pageNumber": "1"}

query = {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"terms": {"type": ["1", "2"]}},
            {"terms": {"status": ["31094502"]}},
            {"term": {"programmePeriod": "2021 - 2027"}},
            {"terms": {"frameworkProgramme": ["43108390"]}},
        ]
    }
}

languages = ["en"]
sort = {"field": "sortStatus", "order": "ASC"}

page = 1
has_more_results = True

while has_more_results:
    params["pageNumber"] = str(page)
    data = requests.post(
        api_url,
        params=params,
        files={
            "query": ("blob", json.dumps(query), "application/json"),
            "languages": ("blob", json.dumps(languages), "application/json"),
            "sort": ("blob", json.dumps(sort), "application/json"),
        },
    ).json()

    for result in data["results"]:
        keywords = result["metadata"]["keywords"][0] 
        content = result["content"]
        url = result["url"]
        print("Project Name:{}\nKeywords: {}".format(content, keywords))
        print("-" * 50)

    has_more_results = len(data["results"]) == int(params["pageSize"])
    page += 1
```

I have tried searching the API documentation and the internet for a solution, but I have not been successful. I have also tried modifying my search parameters, but that did not help.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how I can retrieve the objectives section for each project through the API or something else.

Comment: If you open web inspector you can see it comes from another requests: https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/data/topicDetails/erc-2023-poc.json?lang=en
Unless their API allows for that, you have to parse that json for every project name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what are you pointing at and I tried to parse it using url's of each project but somehow I cant access urls. When I try to go to link, it says it was removed.

Comment: Update the question with new code please

Comment: It's a minor change, but I've updated the code, thank you for the warning. I added the url section now. My goal here was to parse these urls one by one, instead of searching for individual project names.

Comment: You just vandalized your own question, for whatever reason. Why?

Comment: If you want to delete your question, the "delete" link is right next to the "edit" link you used to wreck it.

Comment: Do we have any answer on how to make this work ?